# How to convert Json String into io.restassured.response.Response

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

For one of my requirement, I need to cast **String** in **Json format** into **io.restassured.response.Response** format. In the RestAssured documentation, I didn't find any such straight solution.

Implementation is available to convert String into io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath but not io.restassured.response.Response. How can I convert Json String into Response?